# Changing an annotation to a pin

Tags: swift, annotations, pins

I'm try to make a pin that you click on and a title and subtitle will come up.

Here's my code so far:

```
    let span : MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.1, 0.1)
    let location : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.750517, -73.987271)
    let region : MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

    annotation.coordinate = location
    annotation.title = "Bus Stop"
    annotation.subtitle = "Street Name at Street Name"
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

The problem is mine comes up as a circle bubble which is not what I want, I want those traditional red pins used in apps that when you click on more info shows.

Comment: those red pins are replaced in newer version of iOS.

Comment: @Jack I still see apps that frequently update using the pins though

Comment: They might using custom image in `mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation)`

Comment: @JoshMalway Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

extension YourViewC: MKMapViewDelegate {

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if annotation is MKUserLocation
        {
            return nil
        }
        var annotationView = self.mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "CustomPin")
        if annotationView == nil{
            annotationView = AnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "CustomPin")
            annotationView?.canShowCallout = false
        }else{
            annotationView?.annotation = annotation
        }
        annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: "bluecircle") // Pass name of your custom image
        return annotationView
    }
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView,
             didSelect view: MKAnnotationView){ 
    let annotation = view.annotation as? CustomAnnotation
   print(annotation?.address) // get info you passed on pin

  // write code here to add custom view on tapped annotion
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement delegate method to change the view of annotaion.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
  //Implement Your custom view for annoation
}
```

Comment: could you add my code within your delegate method because I don't really understand